# How to correctly install Git 2.17.1 from source on CentOS 7.4?

Tags: centos, software-installation, git, source

I'd like to install latest available git to day (git-2.17.1), on CentOS 7.4, because some applications are complaining for it, and not only.

I'm trying to install **git-2.17.1** from source on **CentOS 7.4**.

These are the approachs I tried:

- Uninstalled the old git (only) using:

a) `rpm -e --nodeps git`

- Downloaded and extracted the file `git-2.17.1.zip` on `/home/myusername/temp/`
- Changed to the extracted file's directory, in this case `/home/myusername/temp/git-2.17.1/`
- As a super user, installed all supposedly needed dependencies, using:

a) `yum install docbook2X-0.8.8-17.el7.x86_64.rpm` (after having downloaded  this package)

b) `yum install dh-autoreconf curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel perl-devel zlib-devel asciidoc xmlto gengetopt autoconf libcurl-devel gcc kernel-headers debhelper intltool perl-Git po-debconf`

- Created a symlink as instructed on git-scm web site, using:

a)  `ln -s /usr/bin/db2x_docbook2texi /usr/bin/docbook2x-texi`

- As a normal user, ran the following:
- `./configure CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/openssl/include' LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/openssl/lib' --prefix=/usr/local/git --with-openssl=/usr/local/bin/openssl`
- `make all doc info`
- And again, as a super user, ran the following:
- `make install install-doc install-html install-info`

The problem arises on last step, outputting  the following:

```
install -m 644 git.info gitman.info /usr/local/git/share/info
if test -r /usr/local/git/share/info/dir; then \
  install-info --info-dir=/usr/local/git/share/info git.info ;\
  install-info --info-dir=/usr/local/git/share/info gitman.info ;\
else \
  echo "No directory found in /usr/local/git/share/info" >&2 ; \
fi
No directory found in /usr/local/git/share/info
mak
e[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myusername/temp/git-2.17.1/Documentation'
```

> I successfully upgraded openssl version to the latest available today (openssl 1.1.0h).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not error, you can check it with `echo $?` after running `make install-info`.  Target `install-info` in `Documentation/Makefile`
looks like this:

```
install-info: info
    $(INSTALL) -d -m 755 $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 git.info gitman.info $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)
    if test -r $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)/dir; then \
      $(INSTALL_INFO) --info-dir=$(DESTDIR)$(infodir) git.info ;\
      $(INSTALL_INFO) --info-dir=$(DESTDIR)$(infodir) gitman.info ;\
    else \
      echo "No directory found in $(DESTDIR)$(infodir)" >&2 ; \
    fi
```

Program named `install` correctly creates info-pages in
`/usr/local/git/share/info/`, you can check it:

```
$ ls -lh /usr/local/git/share/info/
total 2.3M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 218K Jun 13 21:46 git.info
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.1M Jun 13 21:46 gitman.info
```

The `install-info` target was introduced in commit `4739809c` and says:

> If the info target directory does not already contain a "dir" file, no
>   directory entry is created.

A file named `dir` is a part of [`GNU texinfo`](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Directory-File.html#Directory-File)
but it's not required.

Also notice that unless you have `/usr/local/git/bin/` in your `$PATH` you cannot start `git` by simply typing `git` after installing it the way you did, you have to do this instead:

```
$ /usr/local/git/bin/git --version
git version 2.17.1
```

Comment: It worked I just needed to properly set the $PATH, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

> How to correctly install Git 2.17.1 from source on CentOS 7

Probably build the "2.17.1" packages, and install the required packages with yum.

Source package 
ftp://ftp.icm.edu.pl/vol/rzm6/linux-fedora/linux/updates/28/Everything/SRPMS/Packages/g/git-2.17.1-2.fc28.src.rpm

Setup `$HOME/rpms/` https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/need-rpm-package-for-php-version-5-2-7-and-up-on-redhat-5-1-a-766486/#13

```
$ rpm -i git-2.17.1-2.fc28.src.rpm

# yum install libcurl-devel libsecret-devel pcre2-devel tk cvs cvsps \ 
httpd mod_dav_svn subversion subversion-perl perl-DBD-SQLite perl-CPAN

# cpan
cpan[1]> install IO::Pty
cpan[2]> install Test::More


$ cd rpms/SPECS/
$ rpmbuild -bb git.spec
.
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/x86_64/git-2.17.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/git-all-2.17.1-2.el7.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/x86_64/git-core-2.17.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/git-core-doc-2.17.1-2.el7.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/git-cvs-2.17.1-2.el7.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/x86_64/git-daemon-2.17.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/git-email-2.17.1-2.el7.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/gitk-2.17.1-2.el7.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/gitweb-2.17.1-2.el7.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/git-gui-2.17.1-2.el7.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/git-p4-2.17.1-2.el7.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/perl-Git-2.17.1-2.el7.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/noarch/perl-Git-SVN-2.17.1-2.el7.noarch.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/x86_64/git-subtree-2.17.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/x86_64/git-svn-2.17.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/x86_64/git-debuginfo-2.17.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

The 16 packages https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PRxoicjzHWunFZW-hhXT9JsFk_PQIoLs?usp=sharing